# MFMailComposeViewController : gives EXC-BAD-EXCESS when dismiss it from parent view

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, dismiss

I have UINavigationController/UITabBarController base application and all is working fine but MFMailComposeViewController driving me crazy. I have go through almost every post of stack overflow about MFMailComposeViewController  and tried it but than after it's give me EXC-BAD-EXCESS  when i am trying to dismiss it from parent view.

Here is my code for MFMailComposeViewController.

```
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error
{    

UIAlertView *alert;
if (result == MFMailComposeResultFailed) {
    alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Message Failed!" message:@"Your email has failed to send" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}

[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
//[controller dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
//[[self parentViewController]dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

I don't know where is my mistake or what is wrong with this mail composer. Pleas provide some guide line.

For more code..here i ma providing code...

```
-(void)mailsender
 {
  NSUserDefaults *invoiceautogenerator = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
 NSString *invoicestring = [invoiceautogenerator objectForKey:@"invoice"];

NSString *MemoString = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"SALEMEMODETAIL"];
NSString *PassUniqeNumer = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"UNIQUREFKEYDATA"];

MFMailComposeViewController *mail1 = [[[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init]autorelease];

mail1.mailComposeDelegate = self;


[self databaseOpen];
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Select EmailID from tblMercuryDetail"];
NSLog(@"str:%@",str);
NSArray *Query = [[NSArray alloc]init];
Query = [database executeQuery:str];
NSLog(@"Array DataL%@",Query);

NSString *Emailid = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[Query valueForKey:@"EmailID"]] ;
NSLog(@"Emailid:%@",Emailid);

Emailid = [Emailid stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(" withString:@""];
Emailid = [Emailid stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@")" withString:@""];
Emailid = [Emailid stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@""];
Emailid = [Emailid stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
NSLog(@"Emailid:%@",Emailid);
[Query release];
[database close];



UIImage *savedimage = [self loadImage:invoicestring];

NSData *myData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(savedimage);

[mail1 addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"sign.png"];

if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
    //Setting up the Subject, recipients, and message body.
    [mail1 setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:Emailid,nil]];
    [mail1 setSubject:@"Receipt"];
    [mail1 setMessageBody:@"Message of email" isHTML:NO];
    NSString *emailBody;

    [self databaseOpen];

    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Select * from tblGiftTransaction where InvoiceNo = '%@' ",invoicestring];

    NSArray *Arraydata = [[NSArray alloc]init];
    Arraydata = [database executeQuery:str];

    NSString *PurchaseAmt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[Arraydata valueForKey:@"PurchaseAmt"]];
    NSString *TransactionType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[Arraydata valueForKey:@"TransactionType"]];

    NSLog(@"==%@",Arraydata);


              emailBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@
                             "<br>Memo:                  </br> " "%@"
                             "<br>Ref Number:            </br> ""%@"
                             "<br>Invoice No:            </br> ""%@"
                             "<br>Purchase Amount:       </br> ""$%@"
                             "<br>Transaction Type:      </br> ""%@"
                            ,MemoString,PassUniqeNumer,invoicestring,PurchaseAmt,TransactionType
                           ]; 

    NSLog(@"%@",emailBody);

            [mail1 setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:YES];
    [[self parentViewController] presentModalViewController:mail1 animated:YES];
    [database close];


        }  

  //[mail release];
 }
```

Thanks.

Comment: `[controller dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];` should work

Comment: please provide more code details.

Comment: @beryllium : I have used it.But it's not working...thanks..

Comment: @Priyanka: See my edit in post...i have added some more code.

Comment: @Nit replace this line  [[self parentViewController] presentModalViewController:mail1 animated:YES];
 by [self presentModalViewController:mail1 animated:YES];

Comment: @priyanka : I also did that..but not working....thanks for reply..

Comment: @Nit have you replace above line in mailsender function.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9595/discussion-between-priyanka-and-nit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently did this for my project, and it's working fine. I'm not %100 sure what's wrong with your code, however here is my code, if you wish to compare. Please comment if you need more help.

```
- (IBAction)EmailMe:(id)sender
{
    //Open MFMail and set Preferences

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
    [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage * image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    MFMailComposeViewController *mailComposer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    [mailComposer setMailComposeDelegate:self];
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image,1.0);
    if([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]){
        [mailComposer setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Youremail@email.com", nil]];
        [mailComposer setSubject: @"Subject"];
        [mailComposer setMessageBody:@"Hello, \n\n how are you?" isHTML:NO];
//if you want to attach an image


[mailComposer addAttachmentData:imageData mimeType:@"image/jpeg" fileName:@"attachment.jpg"];
        [mailComposer setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];



        [self presentModalViewController:mailComposer animated:YES];
    }

}

//Dismiss MFmail
-(void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error
{
    if(error)
    {
        UIAlertView *alert= [[UIAlertView alloc]
                             initWithTitle:@"Error %@"
                             message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error %@", [error description]]
                             delegate:self  
                             cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" 
                             otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];

    }

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my working code to implement the method.
Note that I compared your method with mine. They appear to be similar.
You may also wish to try cleaning your project prior to building and instantiating the 
entire alert object before the if statement.

```
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller  
didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error 
{   
switch (result)
{
    case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
        emailMsg = @"email canceled";
        break;
    case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
        emailMsg = @"email saved";
        break;
    case MFMailComposeResultSent:
        emailMsg = @"email sent";
        break;
    case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
        emailMsg = @"email failed";
        break;
    default:
        emailMsg = @"email not sent";
        break;
}

NSString *msgResult;
msgResult = emailMsg;
NSLog(@"msgResult %@", msgResult);
UIAlertView *avMsgResult = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Mail Status"  
message:msgResult delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[avMsgResult show];
[avMsgResult release];


[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```